# how to send a email relation already existing with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

i have a model Pipeline, if create pipeline, will send a email, update pipeline will send a email, now i want to update pipeline send a email relation  previous create pipeline email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[like this create and update email in one mail.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2dwk.jpg)

Comment: references: "#{message_id}"